# How to Style a tfoot footer when printing so the last occurrence if the footer will be at the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css, footer

I'm using a CRM application that creates pdf documents based on htmls.
As part of the document I need to use a header and a footer that will be placed at the top and bottom of every page regardless of the size of the page.
The header is working ok and also the footer, except in the last page.
The footer is being placed at the end of the text and not at the end of the page.

I tried using last-child, last-of-type and it's not working.
Even playing with the padding and margins didn't work - well, it changed all the footers.
How can I reach to only the last one.

To simplify the tests I'm trying to change the text color of only the last occurrence of the footer.
How can I do it?

Here is my code:

```
<div>
<style>
.raz {
 color:green;
}

tfoot.row2 {
color:red;
}

</style>
</div>

<body>
<div style="margin-right: 1.84cm;margin-left: 2cm;width: 21cm; direction:rtl">
<table style="border:none;" class="raz">
    <thead align="left" style="display: table-header-group">
        <tr>
            <th>
            <table style="border-bottom: 1px solid Black; margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 20px; width: 100%">
                <tbody>
                

<tr>
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle; font-family: Times New Roman; font-size: 20px;color: Navy">
                        <div style="float: right">abcdefg</div>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 50px; vertical-align: middle"><img alt="Logo Image" src="https://xxxxxxxxxxxx/logo.png" style="width: 120px; border: 0px; " /></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

<tfoot class="row2">

            <tr>
              
                <td>
                <div class="row" style="text-align:center;padding-top:1cm;margin-bottom:1cm;">
                <span style="font-family:tahoma,geneva,sans-serif;font-size:16px;">This is the footer<br />
                This is the second line of the footer</span></div>
                </td>
             
            </tr>

    </tfoot>
<!-- table body -->
<tbody>
    <!--<div style="height:27.5cm;">-->
    <tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr>
    <tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr>
    <tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr>
    <tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr><tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr><tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr><tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr><tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr><tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr><tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr><tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr><tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr>
    <tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr><tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr><tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr>
    <tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr><tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr><tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr><tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr><tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr><tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr>
    <tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr><tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr><tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr><tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr>
    <tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr><tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr><tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr><tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr><tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr>
    <tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr><tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr><tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr><tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr><tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr>
    <tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr><tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr><tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr><tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr><tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr><tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr>
    <tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr><tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr><tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr><tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr><tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr>
    <tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr><tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr><tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr><tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr>
    <tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr><tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr><tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr><tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr>
    <tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr><tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr><tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr><tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr>
    
</tbody>    
</table>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use tfoot only for what you want. So you should change your source like below:

```css
.raz {
    color:green;
}

tfoot.row2 {
    color:red;
}

@media print {
    #spacer {height: 2em;} /* height of footer + a little extra */
    #footer {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<div style="margin-right: 1.84cm;margin-left: 2cm;width: 21cm; direction:rtl">
    <table style="border:none;" class="raz">
        <thead align="left" style="display: table-header-group">
        <tr>
            <th>
                <table style="border-bottom: 1px solid Black; margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 20px; width: 100%">
                    <tbody>


                    <tr>
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle; font-family: Times New Roman; font-size: 20px;color: Navy">
                            <div style="float: right">abcdefg</div>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 50px; vertical-align: middle"><img alt="Logo Image" src="https://xxxxxxxxxxxx/logo.png" style="width: 120px; border: 0px; " /></td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </th>
        </tr>
        </thead>

        <tfoot class="row2">

        <tr valign="bottom">
            <td id="spacer"></td>
        </tr>

        </tfoot>
        <!-- table body -->
        <tbody>
        <!--<div style="height:27.5cm;">-->
        <tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr>
        <tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr>
        <tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr>
        <tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr><tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr><tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr><tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr><tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr><tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr><tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr><tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr><tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr>
        <tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr><tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr><tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr>
        <tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr><tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr><tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr><tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr><tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr><tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr>
        <tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr><tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr><tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr><tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr>
        <tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr><tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr><tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr><tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr><tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr>
        <tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr><tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr><tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr><tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr><tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr>
        <tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr><tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr><tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr><tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr><tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr><tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr>
        <tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr><tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr><tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr><tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr><tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr>
        <tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr><tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr><tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr><tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr>
        <tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr><tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr><tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr><tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr>
        <tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr><tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr><tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr><tr><td>raz rosman is gever gever</td></tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>

    <div id="footer">
        <span style="font-family:tahoma,geneva,sans-serif;font-size:16px;">This is the footer<br />
                This is the second line of the footer</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, It's not working. I tried to use the same code as yours and I still get the result where in the last page the footer is near the text and not at the end of the page. Any suggestions? Thanks